# Add more items to the model and Session

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, shopping-cart

In my shopping cart i have passed data through Session.In here i face some problem there's 2 additional fields in Shopping cart.How do i add that one to my model.Because model not bind to this view.

### Models

```
public class CartTotal
{
    public decimal SubTotal { get; set; }
    public decimal DeliveryCharges { get; set; }
    //Some properties here
    public List<Items> items { get; } = new List<Items>();
}

public class Items
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string ItemCode { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public string PersonalizedName { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }

}
```

Before coming to the Cart i have added the items using ItemsHolder.

### ItemHolder

```
 public CartTotal ItemsHolder
 {
        get
        {
            object ItemsSession = Session["ItemSession"] as CartTotal;

            if (ItemsSession == null)
            {
                ItemsSession = new CartTotal();
                Session["ItemSession"] = ItemsSession;
            }

            return (CartTotal)ItemsSession;
        }
}
```

I added items like below in item add section,

```
public ActionResult AddNewItems(int ItemId,string Dir)
{
   ItemsHolder.items.Add(new Items() {
                ItemId = items.ItemId,
                ItemName = items.ItemName,
                ItemPrice = items.ItemPrice,
                ImageUrl = items.ImageUrl,
                ItemCode = items.ItemCode
            });
   return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

NOW the problem is I have use that ItemSession in the Cart and in the Items dto has 2 properties called PersonalizedName & Size those fields filled it on the cart section.and i need to add those things to the ItemHolder.How do i do it?

### my _cart Partial View

```
@{
    var list = Session["ItemSession"] as XYZ.Domain.CartTotal;
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("CartFinalize", "Home"))
{
            @foreach (var item in list.items)
            {
                // Some Codes here
                <td class="cart-itm">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control personalizedName" placeholder="Personalized Name">
                </td>
                <td class="cart-itm">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control size" placeholder="Size">
               </td>
          }
}
```

I need to add those 2 items to the Specific item in the Cart.

Comment: I have read your question twice but didn't understand clearly what you are actually wanting. Would please add some comment in your code specifying what are you expecting in where?

Comment: Can not you do `PersonalizedName  = items.PersonalizedName ` ?